# Informatica Dynamic Data Masking RoutePeer-2.serverData: Failed with: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: postgresql, sockets

We recently were working on a project that required using tableau with dynamic data masking service.

Things all work fine till we try to extract a large table with approx. 20000000 records (about 10 G) of data thru ddm proxy, the connection will automatically reset and ddm log will show:

```
[DDM for PostgreSQL] ERROR - RoutePeer-2.serverData: Failed with:

java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

     at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.Write0(Native Method)
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcherImpl.Write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
     at com.activebase.c.b.c.write(c.java:126)
     at com.activebase.c.b.a.b.write(b.java:385)
     at com.activebase.router.a.a(a.java:421)
     at com.activebase.router.a.serverData(a.java:286) at
com.activebase.protocol.AbstractProtocol.dispatchServerDataEvent(AbstractProtocol.java:126)
com.activebase.router.AbstractProtocol.serverData(AbstractProtocolAdapter.java:144)
at com.activebase.dnr.DNRProtocolAdapter.serverData(DNRProtocolAdapter.java:107)........
```

However, if we switch back to direct db connection without using ddm, everything works fine. So is it because DDM are incapable of pass large amount of records such as 10 G of data? or if DDM does support pass large amount of data, is there any configuration we can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, DDM is positioned between the original data resource. 
For application users, DDM is just a gateway to pass the database request.
In order to achieve this masking, a rule can be configured in DDM

I am using the Mentis for [Dynamic Data masking](https://www.mentisinc.com/dynamic-data-masking/) and [Static Data masking](https://www.mentisinc.com/static-data-masking/) for higher data volumes..